# Error :: " Error creating bean with name" In Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

**Wild Fly Server Log :: **
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService'; 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
Spring Service Implementation Code ::

```
    package com.edifixio.training.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.edifixio.training.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.edifixio.training.entity.Customer;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;


    @Transactional
    public List < Customer > getCustomers() {
        return customerDAO.getCustomers();
    }


    @Transactional
    public void saveCustomer(Customer theCustomer) {
        customerDAO.saveCustomer(theCustomer);
    }


    @Transactional
    public Customer getCustomer(int theId) {
        return customerDAO.getCustomer(theId);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void deleteCustomer(int theId) {
        customerDAO.deleteCustomer(theId);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's good to provide the code to the service, but without the code of the injection, it might be hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of the error is :

> No qualifying bean of type
>   'com.edifixio.training.service.CustomerService' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Your service `CustomerServiceImpl` is missing the `implements` part, and will never be considered as a `CustomerService` bean .

Just declare the class as :

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService
```